# Return records from this week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE TB
WHERE TB.DATE >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND TB.DATE <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

My dates look like this: `2015-01-19 00:00:00`

Currently my query returns no records. I want to return records from this week. Anything created from Monday to Sunday.

I am using SQL Server `10.50.1617`

Comment: Do you care about the `TIME` portion of the `TB.DATE` column? If not, a `CAST(TB.DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()` may suffice.

Comment: My data doesnt have time... it is always 00:00:00

Comment: Try my above suggestion to see if that would work for you. As written it will check dates from within a week of today.

Comment: create two variables, set them to start date, and end date. select them so you can see the value. Then manually run a script with the actual dates to see if you return value. Troubleshoot--that's how you'll figure it out. Take steps.

Comment: data doesn't show up... it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it will find all data from this week from monday to sunday:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE TB
WHERE 
  TB.DATE >= dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, current_timestamp)/7*7)
  AND TB.DATE <  dateadd(d, 7, datediff(d, 0, current_timestamp)/7*7)
```

Comment: `TB.DATE <  dateadd(d, 7,`
here should be 6 i believe

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri no, this is selecting from monday to just before next monday

Comment: Of course, i`ve missed that B.DATE < strictly is less. Yes, interesting method.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for current week Monday - Sunday:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE TB
WHERE TB.DATE >= (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, getdate()) / 7 * 7, - 0)) 
  AND TB.DATE <=  DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate())+ 1  , + 2)
```

This will get you prior week Monday - Sunday:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE TB
WHERE TB.DATE >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE())-1, 7) 
  AND TB.DATE <=  (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, getdate()) / 7 * 7, - 1))
```